# StringBuilder.ToString() throw an 'Index out of range' Exception

Tags: c#, exception, tostring, stringbuilder

I would really appreciate someone help me resolving the following issue:

I am getting now and then the following exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: chunkLength

on `stringBuilder.ToString()`.

What is strange is if I put `stringBuilder.ToString()` in the watch, it works perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible that your StringBuilder is also being used by another thread?

Comment: Could you provide the snippit that causes the exception including how string builder is built up?

Comment: The stringBuilder.AppendLine is called on an events. It is then displayed on the screen on a different thread.

Comment: @GerhardPowell, that's probably the cause of your problem. StringBuilder is not thread-safe, it shouldn't be used concurrently from different threads. If you need to display it from a different thread, pass the result of ToString to the other thread, not the StringBuilder itself.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Look like it is a multi thread issue. I locked the thread to prevent multi access to the stringBuilder at the same time.

```
public void AddString(string s)
{
  lock(this.LockObject)
  {
     StringBuilder.AppendLine(s);
  }
}
```